# Compute size of b/w shape in 2D Plane

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, size

I want to compute the number of black pixel in arbitrary shapes in a picture. There might be several objects, like in the picture at the bottom.

I suspect that the problem is solveable with dynamic programming, i.e. traverse the pixels row-wise and add the black pixels. I just don't know how to correctly unite the size of two parts.

I'm pretty sure there are algorithms that solve my problem, but i obviously use the wrong search terms.

Can you please provide me with a good (fast) algorithm to do so, Bonus points if the algorithm is written in c++ and compatible to Mat from the OpenCV library. ;)

[image: Example Image]

Result for this (zoomed) picture would be something like: 15 for Object at top left, 60 for big blob,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a solution (better ones are obviously welcome!):

Integrated the size computation into a [Connected Component Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).

In the Connected Component algorithm, we generate a new Image in which there are labels (numbers) instead of the black pixels. All pixel of one area have the same label.

New to CC-Algo is a table in which the total amount of pixel for each label is stored. That way i know for every connected component the correct size.

```
Process the image from left to right, top to bottom:
1.) If the next pixel to process is white:
    do nothing
2.) If the next pixel to process is black:
    i.) If only one of its neighbors (top or left) is black, copy its label and +1 in the size table for that label.
    ii.) If both are black and have the same label, copy it and +1 in the size table for that label.
    iii.) If they have different labels Copy the label from the left. Update the equivalence table and +1 in the size table for the left label.
iv.) Otherwise, assign a new label and update the size table with that label and value 1.

• Re-label with the smallest of equivalent labels and update size table accordingly
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved using flood fill in following way : -

> 1. Keep 2-D boolean array to track if pixel is already visited initially set to false
> 2. scan the image pixel by pixel.
> 3. if pixel is unvisited and black then apply flood fill on it,
> 4. During floodfill count the number of call also mark visited pixel made as they are the no of pixels connected.
> 5. Terminate floodfill when white pixels are encountered.
> 6. Count is the size of the region containing the pixel.

[Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Comment: i will test that, i'm excited to see if fllodfill+counting is faster then Connected Component+counting.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understoud, in an image like your sample you want your alogirthm to return 6 values on for each black shapes. And, each value the number of black pixels.

The algorithm I would use for this is the following :

1. Invert Pixels colors of your image (so now, you are looking for white pixels)
2. [Find contours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) in your image. Don't forget to find only EXTERNAL Countours.
3. For each contours found :
   [Draw each contour](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours) in a small cv::Mat with a pixel value of 1. then compute the [moment of order](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#moments) 0 of this image. The moment of order 0 will be the number of pixel in the shape.

Comment: Sounds promising, i will report tomorrow if it is faster than my homebrew solution!

Comment: It's probably slower than a method like the one described in you response, but it will be faster to code and to test... And as time is money, maybe your manager will prefer my method (it depends of your constraints)

Comment: Finding contours is far too complicated compared to flood-fill, which takes care of holes too.